# Highcharts-exporting-server gives - phantom - queue is full, dropping request Error

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts-exporting-server to generate chart images in batch. And I have around 1000 images to create at a time.

> running it inside node server.

here's the code

```
exporter.initPool(); 
_.forEach(configs, (config, index) => {
    exporter.export(new ExporterSettings('png', config), (err, resp) => {
        if(resp && resp.data) {
            base64_decode(resp.data, `test-chart-${index}.png`);
        }
    });
});
```

Where `base64_decode()` is just writing base64-encoded data to a ***`.png`*** file.

Everything works fine but for 10 -15 images but then I get error

> phantom - queue is full, dropping request **Error**

this error comes from phantompool.js

```
if (workQueue.length > 5) {
    queueOverflow++;
    log(2, 'phantom - queue is full, dropping request');
    return fn && fn('server too busy, please try again later');
}
```

Seems like some logic to  keep workers warm.

> if I change 
>   `if (workQueue.length > 5)` to `if (workQueue.length > 9999)` in phantompool.js
>   everything works smooth without any error.

I don't know if I am missing some configuration.
I know we can pass in some config in `exporter.initPool();` but not sure about that.

Any suggestion/help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Worker count and limit settings are explained in [the node export server documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#worker-count--work-limit). If this doesn't work then it could be a bug, so you could [report it](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues).

Comment: Curious if you were able to configure the queue size or talk with Highcharts support about this? (I didn't notice a github issue, though I did see a related issue where they mention their justification for the queue size)

I'm using the export server as a node module and running locally (running node on a macbook pro) in a series of node scripts which export + calculate data and generate chart config for anywhere up to about 500 charts.

The only way I've been able to get this workflow to scale is by increasing the queue size.

Comment: FYI: I've just [opened an issue](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/136); will share the response here.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I don't really like the idea of increasing the number of workers to 100+.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the issue opened by Jes Constantine above, a fix is now available: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/commit/e6e2449d1d67719c116df46a859f5fccbccefc1a , although as of today (2018-Jun-11) it in master, not in any release.

So if you install it with:

```
npm install https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/archive/2d07efcab1ab37660228736a5e6a3196f64be617.tar.gz --save
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
exporter.initPool({
  maxWorkers: 8,
  initialWorkers: 8,
  workLimit: 50,
  queueSize: 500
});
```

Which solved the issue in question for me.